# Can't Override Default Font Globally on MUI Theme

Tags: typescript, material-ui

**Objective:**
I'm trying to override the default font using MUI themes.

**Problem:** After reading MUI documentation, and stack overflow research, I'm unable to override a self hosted font globally across the theme.

**Theme file**:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import VCRMonoWoff2 from './fonts/VcrMono.woff2';
import VCRMonoWoff from './fonts/VcrMono.woff';

const theme = createTheme({
    typography: {
      fontFamily: 'VCRMono',
    },
    components: {
      MuiCssBaseline: {
        styleOverrides: `
          @font-face {
            font-family: 'VCRMono';
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            src: url(${VCRMonoWoff2}) format('woff2'), url(${VCRMonoWoff}) format('woff');
            unicodeRange: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF;
          }
        `,
      },
    },
  });
export default theme;
```

**Usage**:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { CssBaseline } from '@mui/material';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

import theme from './theme';

export default function Example() {
    return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <Box>Example3</Box>
  </ThemeProvider>
);
}
```

This doesn't update my theme typography to the new font. However, if I run this code, the font is updated to VCRMono:

```
export default function Example() {
    return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <Box sx={{
        fontFamily: 'VCRMono',
      }}>Example3</Box>
  </ThemeProvider>
);
}
```

Although, this doesn't meet my objective as I am trying to override the default font globally.

[MUI Self Hosted Fonts Documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/typography/#self-hosted-fonts) states: "you need to change the theme to use this new font. In order to globally define  as a font face, the CssBaseline component can be used." I tried replicating these steps and wasn't able to accomplish the task.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: A follow up question is do we always need to specify the sx prop in order to override the font or other property? Can overriding be accomplished without using the sx prop?

Comment: I answered my own question, the sx prop is not required. Please look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above was correct, although, the root was not wrapped in the ThemeProvider class.

This is the fix:

```
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}><Example/></ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

Wrap ThemeProvider around the root to enforce it globally.
This is present in the [documentation around theming](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#themeprovider).

Although, it's in a different location from typography so I missed it earlier.